# Text disappears after switching page

Tags: javascript, jquery

For the website I am working on,

> http://ChinaStampedConcrete.com

if you scroll down, you will see "Need a Professional Floor Solution?"

I added this text with jQuery, but if you switch pages; clicking on any tabs on the menu bar at top, this text disappears. Only if you refresh the page, the text will reappear again. I tried searching for a solution, and I haven't figured one out yet. Can anyone help please, or any other suggestion; perhaps using JavaScript?

The code I wrote is:

```js
$j(document).ready(function() {
    // For custom content bottom
    var $callToAction = $j(".content_bottom .call_to_action .text_wrapper");
    var $divToInsert = $j("<div>", { class: "call_to_action_header" });

    $divToInsert.text("Need A Professional Floor Solution?");
    $callToAction.prepend($divToInsert);
});
```

Comment: remove the code and try this -  $(".text_wrapper").append("<div class='call_to_action_header'>Need A Professional Floor Solution?</div>");

Comment: I'm a bit confused, when does it disappear (1)? and 2, why are you doing this with jQuery instead of basic HTML?

Comment: Well you remove the text so you would need to add it back when you switch back to that tab.

Comment: because the page is done using wordpress by someone else, and I am just adding these little things.

Comment: @Thinker, remove the entire code? I have to make sure  that it is appended to the content_bottom

Comment: ***Just a tip:** You know that there is a text property available when creating a jQuery element?* http://pastebin.com/Ei64jBUP

Comment: You could put your code in a function and call it whenever you call home (link click) and on $document.ready()...

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
$(".content_bottom .call_to_action .text_wrapper").append("<div class='call_to_action_header'>Need A Professional Floor Solution?</div>");
```

or you can create a div and prepend like this :

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.className = "call_to_action_header";
div.innerHTML = "Need A Professional Floor Solution?";

var $callToAction = $(".content_bottom .call_to_action .text_wrapper");
$callToAction.prepend(div);
```

Here is the sample [model1](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/jay7qzen/) and [model2](https://jsfiddle.net/AK_Spikey/jay7qzen/1/)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: doesn't seem to be working :( the text wouldn't even show up this case

Comment: sorry I made some typo, but yeah it works the same way, if I change page using tab, say going from Home to Article, the text disappears

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are dynamically **injecting this element on DOM** after the complete DOM is loaded using the **document.ready** function , when you move away from the page using tabs or links,  this element get removed from the DOM and when you come back to the page since this time **document.ready** function will not be executed hence the element and the text both will be missing.

you should put your code in a function which will always be called whenever user is visiting the home page.